# How can i get django to stop returning "Response code: 403" to iPhone App

Tags: python, iphone, django, swift, django-views

I have the following swift code for my iPhone app:

```
        var post:NSString = "username=\(username)&password=\(password)"

        NSLog("PostData: %@",post);

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8000/straightred/login/")!

        var postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)


        let res = response as NSHTTPURLResponse!;

        NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);
```

The code above gives me the following result in the xcode output window:

2015-04-22 20:30:03.768 SwiftLoginScreen[2290:70315] PostData: username=test&password=password

2015-04-22 20:30:03.821 SwiftLoginScreen[2290:70315] Response code: 403

Below is the django views.py part (although in all honesty it seems it will not matter what is put here as the error 403 is returned before any code is run):

```
@require_POST
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user and user.is_active:
        return HttpResponse("{\"succes:1\" }",content_type = 'application/json')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("{\"success\":0,\"error_message\":\"Invalid Data\"}",content_type = 'application/json')
```

So, in summary, do I need to add something to my iphone app and / or django setup to allow requests from my iPhone app?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks, Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/) related problem.

Try decorating the views accessed by the iPhone App with [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt).

Comment: I would upvote you but I am not allowed yet as I am not important enough yet lol.  Many many thanks.